# Java use variables from another Class

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

Good Day Stackoverflow people!

I stumbled upon a simple problem and I can't find a solution to it by myself.

There are two methods in my Transform class with variables which I want to call in another class but I can't figure out how:

Transform Class Methods:

```
public Vector3f GetPos() {       
    return m_pos;
}

public void SetPos(Vector3f pos) {
    this.m_pos = pos;
}
```

The variables "m_pos" and "pos" are coordinates of a Vector3f which I need to use in a method called ProcessText which is in a different class:

Class2 Method:

```
public void ProcessText() {       
    String file_name = "C:/Users/Server/Desktop/textText.txt";

    try {
        ProcessCoords data = new ProcessCoords(file_name);
        data.writeToFile("makeGrass:0,1,2");

        System.out.println("Coordinates Saved!");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now instead of having the ProcessText method write to the file "makeGrass:0,1,2" I want it to use "m_pos" and "pos" from the methods in my Transform Class, so I can say:

```
data.writeToFile("makeGrass:" + m_pos + pos);
```

However I have no idea how to do get the variables "m_pos" and "pos" from both methods of my Transform Class, if anyone could help me out I would be very happy.

Comment: Use Java Naming Conventions:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 0):

OK. First thing first: pos is not a **member** variable but it is a **parameter** in the method named setPos.

And in order to use m_pos, all you need to do is to have an instance of the Transform class in your 2nd class, let's say it is transform and then you need to call

```
transform.GetPos()
```

to use it.

Comment: *"pos is not a variable but it an argument"* If we're going to get picky about terminology, in Java they're called [*parameters*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1), not arguments. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I need SetPos too since GetPos always prints a bunch of empty coordinates while SetPos only prints coordinates when I push the enter key, if I use GetPos it will always give me (0,0,0).. is it even possible to use SetPos in this case?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - aside from the fact that it IS a variable.  A parameter is just one kind of variable.  This is a very confused answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right. Thanks for the correction. =]

Comment: @DisasterCoder By variable, I meant member variable. I thought it was quite obvious from the context but looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The method in Transform class are getter and setter method they both access same variable so you can not have different value for an instance variable at same time

```
ublic Vector3f GetPos()
{       
    return m_pos;
}

public void SetPos(Vector3f pos)
{
    this.m_pos = pos;
}
```

and to access this field all you need to create object of Transform class and call the setter and getter eg.

```
Transform obj = new Transform();
obj.SetPOS(pos);
```

and to access this value

```
obj.GetPos();
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found stuff out by myself and stumbled upon a different problem and made a new answer which described more accuratly what I wanted to achieve.

What I wanted to use is my GetPos method but I shouldn't do that from my Transform class - althought it would be feasible. I've come up with a different thing: Turns out that my Input class extends the Transform class and I am able to call GetPos() from there.

I've solved the issue now, so for more details on the matter go look here: [Java using code from method doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504073/java-using-code-from-method-doesnt-work)

Thanks for any help so far!